# Running wso2 esb server

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 with JDK 1.7.0_60 on Windows and I get the following error when I start the server.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\WIN>"C:\Program Files\wso2esb-4.8.1\bin\wso2server.bat" --run
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\..
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:191)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:823)
        at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Agent.java:144)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:264)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:456)
Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with the same JDK and did not get this error in Windows 8.1 and Windows 7.
Can you start the server with out "--run" and check?

Comment: It was my mistake. I didn't have the full set of wso libraries copied. Pls delete this question if possible. Sorry for the trouble.